(Small snippet) How can I change my code to make Firefox initial download options change using selenium webdriver
Image showing what I want to change, I want it to save the file upon opening in browser rather than opening in Firefox
This is a small snippet of my code, but it attempts to change the preference based Selenium's built in pref changer, I didn't do much more than basic set up a Firefox profile or anything because I saw pretty differing opinions online but basically I'm struggling to find a good answer for what I'm doing incorrectly or if I just need to do better setup or what-
help would be appreciated, thanks
code snippet below
fp=webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
fp.set_preference(key="application/pdf", value="save")



Invalid key name: The key you are using ("application/pdf") is not correct. You must use special keys used by Firefox to manage file downloads.
Incorrect use of set_preference: The set_preference method receives the key as the first parameter and its value as the second parameter.
from selenium import webdriver
# Create a Firefox profile
fp = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()

# Settings to automatically download PDF files instead of opening them in the browser
fp.set_preference("browser.download.folderList", 2)  # 2: Use the folder you specify
fp.set_preference("browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting", False)
fp.set_preference("browser.download.dir", "/path/to/your/download/directory")  # Desired path to save the file
fp.set_preference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk", "application/pdf")  # Save PDF files without asking
fp.set_preference("pdfjs.disabled", True)  # Disable PDF display in browser

# Create a browser object with the profile set
driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=fp)

# Using the driver to do things...

Description:
browser.download.folderList: This setting specifies where to download files. A value of 2 means to use the folder specified by browser.download.dir.
browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting: This setting will not show the download manager window.
browser.download.dir: specifies the path of the directory where the files should be saved.
browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk: Specifies the type of files to save without asking. In this case, PDF files.
pdfjs.disabled: This option disables PDF display inside the browser so that files are downloaded instead of displayed.
#python #Selenium

This worked, with the exception of two lines which I ended up changing from
fp = webdriver.FirefoxProfile() -> fp = webdriver.FirefoxOptions()
and driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=fp) -> browser = webdriver.Firefox(fp)
